# IOS dealloc never gets called

Tags: ios, dealloc

I have a navigation-based app that switches between some ViewControllers.
If I press the "goHome" button, the method `popViewControllerAnimated:` is called and I return to the main screen. There is a problem though : the dealloc method doesn't get called nor all the elements in that previous view get released. All the animations/UI elements remain hanging in the memory. What should I do?

Comment: This is a leak. You need to fugue out what's causing the leak. The Instruments leaks tool should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it’s a good idea to switch to Automatic Reference Counting, would make your life easier. Second, make sure that there is no more retained reference to the controller or other objects.

Funny story, once I forgot to set an `NSFetchedResultsController`’s delegate to nil and other memory errors and got an ugly exception when the fetched results controller tried to call the delegate, but it was already gone.

Comment: ARC doesn't have less problems with leaks. You just write slightly less code. Newbies in Obj-C should start with MRC to understand what's happening in ARC.

Comment: For understanding reference counting and its caveats, I suggest implementing it manually in C, with lots of output so you can watch what's going on. Objective C without ARC feels rather pointless - the gap between the high-level aspirations of Objective C with Cocoa and Grand Central Dispatch paired with manual retain and release calls has been such an ugly paradox for way long enough...

Comment: Understanding manual memory management in C alone would still not be enough, there is also this thing with naming conventions that ARC makes use of, which affect even Obj-C/Swift interop. ARC is not a silver bullet, but is sure as hell helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

In your UIViewController make sure that your dealloc has the correct signature and is calling the super view last:

```
 - (void) dealloc {
     //Release your stuff
     [super dealloc];
 }
```

Also remember that when dealing with UIViewControllers you need to deal with memory in viewDidUnload as well (doesn't really address your issue, but thought I'd throw it in there).

Comment: that's exactly what I used and still, nothing. I've put a NSLog to test it and it doesn't get called.